# Mixed binary log by default

Tags: docker, mariadb

I'm using the official MariaDB container. I need binary logs in mixed format, which I currently do by running:

`docker run -it --link mariadb:mysql --rm mariadb sh -c 'exec mysql -h"$MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR" -P"$MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_PORT" -uroot -p"$MYSQL_ENV_MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD"'`

and then

`SET GLOBAL binlog_format = 'MIXED';`

However if I restart the container I have to do it again. Is there a way to enable it by default?

Comment: You can edit the configuration file and add this as default. See http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/65273/how-do-i-make-binlog-format-row-the-start-up-default-in-the-etc-my-cnf-file